# No Implemented Error - PySftp

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysftp

I am trying to connect to a SFTP server through **Pysftp** module using the below code

```
a = pysftp.Connection('xx.yyy.zz.abc',username='abcd',password='xyz@123',log=True)
```

This throws the following error

```
 NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5d0f8343a8c2> in <module>()
----> 1 a = pysftp.Connection('xx.yyy.zz.abc',username='abcd',password='xyz@123',log=True)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp.pyc in __init__(self, host, username, private_key, password, port, private_key_pass, ciphers, log)
    160         if password is not None:
    161             # Using Password.
--> 162             self._transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    163         else:
    164             # Use Private Key.

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.15.2-py2.7.egg\paramiko\transport.pyc in connect(self, hostkey, username, password, pkey, gss_host, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds)
    976             self._preferred_keys = [hostkey.get_name()]
    977 
--> 978         self.start_client()
    979 
    980         # check host key if we were given one

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.15.2-py2.7.egg\paramiko\transport.pyc in start_client(self, event)
    404                 e = self.get_exception()
    405                 if e is not None:
--> 406                     raise e
    407                 raise SSHException('Negotiation failed.')
    408             if event.is_set():    
NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15 instead
```

I have been using this line of code for several months but this error has been coming up only recently.

I am able to connect to the port using WINSCP even now.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way for you will be using the https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko lib itself.

The library is not as simple as the `pysftp` wrapper over it, but there are some pretty comprehensive examples to base on: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos